# Problems when trying to create proxy in WSO2

Tags: cmd, proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

I was training the creating of proxy in wso2, in the tutorial: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sending+a+Simple+Message+Through+the+ESB
and had some problems in pass 2 of: 'Building and deploying SimpleStockQuoteService', when i try to run the wso2server.bat, i receive the message bellow:

```
"Starting Sample Axis2 Server ..."
Using AXIS2_HOME:        C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\wso2ei-6.1.1\samples\axis2Server
Using JAVA_HOME:       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Server could not start due to class loading issue java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: samples.util.SampleAxis2Server.startServer([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

I saw in the internet that it would be because of my jdk version, and i tried the 1.7.0_45 and 1.6.0_45. In this case i had this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

The AXIS2_HOME was created too with the way: 'C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\wso2ei-6.1.1\samples\axis2Server'

I really don't know what happening. If someone could help me i would stay quite grateful.

ps: After tried the tutorial of 584, to change the axis2server.bat, in the git hub, i receive this message:

```
"Starting Sample Axis2 Server ..."
Using AXIS2_HOME:        C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\wso2ei-6.1.1\samples\axis2Server
Using JAVA_HOME:       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[main] INFO  samples.util.SampleAxis2ServerManager  - [SimpleAxisServer] Starting
[SimpleAxisServer] Using the Axis2 Repository : C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\wso2ei-6.1.1\samples\axis2Server\repository
[SimpleAxisServer] Using the Axis2 Configuration File : C:\Oxaguia spk\Trabalhos\Coach IT\Piramidal\Servers\wso2ei-6.1.1\samples\axis2Server\repository\conf\axis2.xml
[main] WARN  org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector  - Unable to determine dialect of the StAX implementation at jar:file:/C:/Oxaguia%20spk/Trabalhos/Coach%20IT/Piramidal/Servers/wso2ei-6.1.1/wso2/components/plugins/axiom_1.2.11.wso2v11.jar!/
[main] FATAL samples.util.SampleAxis2ServerManager  - [SimpleAxisServer] Shutting down. Error starting SimpleAxisServer
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: javax/transaction/SystemException
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:704)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:124)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:887)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
        at samples.util.SampleAxis2ServerManager.start(SampleAxis2ServerManager.java:93)
        at samples.util.SampleAxis2Server.startServer(SampleAxis2Server.java:61)
        at samples.util.SampleAxis2Server.main(SampleAxis2Server.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:688)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
```

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enterprise Integrator 6.1.1 supported on JDK version 1.8.* [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Installation+Prerequisites) (Not supported on lower JDK versions).

The issue you observed is fixed [2](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/570) in the upcoming version.

Comment: Sashika, thank you from your help, but i tried this resolution now, and the a bug, i will put in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd error happens because you are using a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime.

Try both compiling and running on 1.7.

Comment: Strange, that i just change the way in the environment variable of 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45' and running the cmd.

Comment: Bhathiya, i deleted my jdk 1.8, restarted my pc and alter environment variable to use the jdk 1.7. Even so i had the same error, exist some document, where i have to change something, to the wso2 understand that my jdk version is different then the first used?